# How to set datagridview checkbox value while data from database in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I want to set datagridview checkbox value from database but I don't know how.

MySql Query:

```
SELECT students.Name, students.Class, students.Feedback, IF(students.Feedback = 0, 1, 0) 
NotFeedBack FROM students;
```

The result are:

```
====================================================
|Name          |Class        |Feedback |NotFeedBack|
====================================================
|Sandra        |1A           |1        |0          |
|Layla         |2B           |1        |0          |
|Nagisa        |3E           |0        |1          |
|Akabane       |3E           |1        |0          |
====================================================
```

In vb.net I've datagridview1, here I declare and set value from database:

```
Sub show_header()
    datagridview1.Columns.Add("Name", "Name")
    datagridview1.Columns.Add("Class", "Class")
    Dim chk As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
    datagridview1.Columns.Add(chk)
    chk.HeaderText = "Feedback"
    chk.Name = "Feedback"
    Dim ch As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
    datagridview1.Columns.Add(ch)
    ch.HeaderText = "NotFeedBack"
    ch.Name = "ch"
End Sub

Sub LoadData()
    dgvOTSum.Rows.Clear()
    dgvOTSum.Refresh()
    Dim tblot As New tblot
    Dim DtTable As New DataTable
    DtTable = tblot.DetailOT
    With DtTable
        For i = 0 To DtTable.Rows.Count - 1
            dgvOTSum.Rows.Add(.Rows(i).Item(0).ToString(), .Rows(i).Item(1).ToString(), _
                             .Rows(i).Item(2).ToString(), .Rows(i).Item(3).ToString())
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

I want result like this:

[image]

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you don't use databinding? Or just because you havent heard of it or dont know how to do it?

Comment: Hi @Mono, I use datagridview.rows.add because the datagridview possible can add new student and can save to database

Any I idea about that?

thanks

Comment: Hi @JohnG, I used two checkbox columns because I want end user look clearly which was not get feedback yet.

Any idea about that? please guide me

thanks

Comment: Hi @JohnG, thank for your advise. Is my mistake that I don't know to set the feedback variable and public property to boolean.
I'll answer my question below.

Once again, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Region "My declare variable (Class Feedback)"
Private _Name As String
Private _Class As String
Private _Feedback As Boolean
#End Region

#Region "Public Property"
Public Property Name As String
Get
    Return _Name
End Get
Set (value As String)
    _Name = value
End Set
End Property

Public Property Class As String
Get
    Return _Class
End Get
Set (value As String)
    _Class = value
End Set
End Property

Public Property Feedback As Boolean
Get
    Return _Feedback
End Get
Set (value As Boolean)
    _Feedback = value
End Set
End Property
#End Region
```

Function

```
Public Function DetailOT() As DataTable
    Dim sql = "SELECT students.Name, students.Class, students.Feedback, IF(students.Feedback = 0, 1, 0)
NotFeedBack FROM students;"
Try
    dtTable = Controldata.SelectQuery(sql)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
End Try
Return dtTable
```

End Function

Form1

```
Sub show_header()
datagridview1.Columns.Add("Name", "Name")
datagridview1.Columns.Add("Class", "Class")
Dim chk As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
datagridview1.Columns.Add(chk)
chk.HeaderText = "Feedback"
chk.Name = "Feedback"
Dim ch As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
datagridview1.Columns.Add(ch)
ch.HeaderText = "NotFeedBack"
ch.Name = "ch"
End Sub

Sub LoadData()
dgvOTSum.Rows.Clear()
dgvOTSum.Refresh()
Dim tblot As New tblot
Dim DtTable As New DataTable
DtTable = tblot.DetailOT
With DtTable
    For i = 0 To DtTable.Rows.Count - 1
        dgvOTSum.Rows.Add(.Rows(i).Item(0).ToString(), .Rows(i).Item(1).ToString(), _
                         .Rows(i).Item(2).ToString(), .Rows(i).Item(3).ToString())
    Next
End With
End Sub


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    show_header()
    LoadData()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should try databinding.

Second you could try:

```
ch.TrueValue = 1
ch.FalseValue = 0
```